# Reference to an interval of values in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to this language.

I am trying to write "if value[i] is greater than the one of the values on the interval [i-e] to [i-1] from the vector x", where i and e are int, and value[i] x[i] are elements of vector "value" and "x", repectively.

The part that I am having special trouble with is the reference to the values on the interval of the vector x. The code that I have written now (and which is wrong) is as follows,

```
if (value[i] > (reference[i - 1]; reference[i - e]))
```

Comment: This is write code for me type of question. I doubt someone will do your homework for you.

Comment: If you'd like to know whether `value[i]` is greater than any value in this range, you'll have to loop over the range as _searching_ for something always involves loops, just like in real life.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: No, I meant value[i] > reference[i - e] "to" reference[i - 1]. I am more used to R, where one can write "from" "to", but on c++ I am starting to think that it is not possible, or it is not so easy.

Comment: No, you'll need to code it as a loop. C++ doesn't have such constructs.

Comment: @StoryTeller _"C++ doesn't have such constructs."_ Well, there's [`find_if()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - C++ doesn't have a built in expressions to work with ranges. The standard library is awesome, but what I mean in "construct" is something you can rely on even in a minimal freestanding environment.

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to this language.
>
> No, I meant value[i] > reference[i - e] "to" reference[i - 1]. I am more used to R, where one can write "from" "to", but on c++ I am starting to think that it is not possible, or it is not so easy.

C++ doesn't have this kind of built-in facility'*. You need to **iterate the interval "reference[i - e] to reference[i - 1]"**, then **check if your value (`value[i]`) is larger than each element** in the interval.

Consider writing the code, then (if you do not succeed), edit the question with what you tried, or post a different question.

'* - well, there is std::find_if, but it's not built-in.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no "built-in" language construct to do what you require, it is useful to look at the standard library, especially at the algorithms provided. I think one solution to your problem is to use `std::all_of` like this (with `T` being the type stored in the vector)

```
if(std::all_of(reference.cbegin() + i, reference.cbegin() + e + 1, [&value, &i](T ref){ return ref < value[i]; })))
{
    ...
}
```

Or in a concrete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> reference = {3,4,5,6,7};
    std::vector<int> value = {6,7,8,9};

    int i = 1;
    int e = 3;
    if(std::all_of(reference.cbegin() + i - 1, reference.cbegin() + e + 1, [&value, &i](int ref){ return ref < value[i]; }))
    {
        std::cout << "value[" << i << "] greater than all reference[" << i-1 << "] to reference [" << e << "]" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[see it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce3db98046bdcb1f)

But you have to be damn careful not to run outside the arrays with the indices `i` and `j`. Notice for example the `+1` in the second parameter of `std::all_of` is because it needs the iterator *behind* the last value it has to look for.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not have any built-in notion of intervals, however you actually do not need that here.

Checking whether a value is greater than any value in a given internal is equivalent to checking whether a value is greater than the maximum value of said interval, and this can be expressed easily enough in C++ using the [`max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) algorithm:

```
if (value[i] > std::max_element(&reference[i - 1], &reference[i - e])) {
}
```

Note that the range is *half-open*: that is, the position `i - 1` is included and the position `i - e` is excluded.

Also note that the range must be described in the lower-upper bound format, so here `e` better be less than or equal to 1.